# Slow Internet Speed Windows 10 NETSH WINSOCK fixes it

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, netsh

So I have stumbled upon an extremely annoying task I have to do everyday and that is to run `netsh winsock reset catalog` everytime I boot into Windows. I have no idea why this has come about but its suddenly appeared and have no idea how to fix it. Can someone help me understand and hopefully tell me how to fix it?

When I boot into windows and I run a speed test I get less than a meg download but my upload speed is 20MB at least. Run the command and restart windows the download is back up at 70MB plus.

This is via WiFi.

Any ideas?

I can post further info if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update BIOS, Chipset (if applicable), Power Driver, Wireless driver (I assume a wireless connection). Restart and set Power properties for the Wireless card to Maximum performance.  Restart again after changing settings and test. See if the above prevents / stops your daily task.

Comment: When you have the issue and before fixing it, can you run from an admin prompt:
`netsh winsock show catalog > C:\wdc.txt` Then link that file to the question?